# How can i define paste range using find for multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, header, copy

I'm trying to copy multiple columns from one sheet to another. Some of them have the same header, most if them have a header slightly different (in one sheet the header is "address" and in the sheet were i wanted to be pasted is "address line" ). I do not want to define the paste range based on the number of the column or the letter of the column, but based on the header of the column. 
The reason is that the order of the column is changing weekly and also the name of the header so the easiest way that i was able to find is to define all the headers from both sheets using vba code and when the order or the name changed i can modify the code.
I was able to find online the following code and adapt it to my needs (thank you all for sharing your knowledge).

```
Sub Order_columns()
Sheets("Original Data").Select

With Sheets("original data").Rows(1)
   Set t = .Find("address", LookAt:=xlWhole)

     If Not t Is Nothing Then
        Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn.copy _
          Destination:=Sheets("Contract data").Range("f1")---- here the column name is Address line
 With Sheets("original data").Rows(1)
   Set t = .Find("country", LookAt:=xlWhole)

     If Not t Is Nothing Then
        Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn.copy _
          Destination:=Sheets("Contract data").Range("j1") 'here the column name is Country and state
end sub
```

The code is working perfect for finding the column with the header "address", copy it and paste it in the column F. I just want it to paste it were the header is Address line.

Comment: This code cannot work at all as it missing End Ifs and End Withs - please post code as used. What about using `LookAt:=xlpart`?

Comment: Sorry: the code is Sub Order_columns()
Sheets("Original Data").Select
With Sheets("original data").Rows(1)
   Set t = .Find("address", LookAt:=xlWhole)

     If Not t Is Nothing Then
        Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn.copy _
          Destination:=Sheets("Contract data").Range("f1")
 With Sheets("original data").Rows(1)
   Set t = .Find("country", LookAt:=xlWhole)
     If Not t Is Nothing Then
        Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn.copy _
          Destination:=Sheets("Contract data").Range("j1")
Else: MsgBox "Title Not Found"
     End If
        End With
end sub

Comment: Lookat:=xlpart can be helpful, but some of the columns have completely different names.

Comment: How are you going to automate something without patterns @Jenica?? Your goal is impossible. Either you make a list every week header sheet 1 = header sheet 2 and then find them or you just can't.

Comment: @Damien. I want to make a list. The order of the column is the one changing more often than the name of the columns.